# c# Birthday month day limit

Tags: c#

I'm not a C# expert so please keep that in mind while I ask this:
In my C# I have a forms project where the user enters the year,month and day they were born and it tells them the day of week their birthday was on.
I want to make sure the user doesn't enter a date that doesn't exist example:
Feb 30 2018.
So, I want to create a popup message that says "date doesn't exist" to do this I created this code:

```
static string FindDay(int year, int month, int day)
{
    //The reason why we are using a new keyword is because i belive: we are creating a new object and to do that you must use a new keyword.
    //DateTime is its own data type like int or string.
    DateTime birthdayDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);

    string dayOfWeek = birthdayDate.DayOfWeek.ToString(); //Don't confuse the local dayOfWeek varible with the DayOfWeek property
    return dayOfWeek;
}

private void FindButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //The reason(I think) that we are casting to int data types is because its a "DateTime" data type.
    int year = (int)numericYear.Value;
    int month = (int)numericMonth.Value;
    int day = (int)numericDay.Value;
    //Date checking to maek sure date isn't invaild.

    int maxDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    if (day > maxDays)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invaild date");

    }

    string dayString = FindDay(year, month, day);
    MessageBox.Show("You were born on a:" + dayString);
}
```

But when I run in the program  everything runs fine and the message pops up and then after the message I see this:
ERROR:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.'
```

And it pops up at

```
string dayOfWeek = birthdayDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

How can I fix this issue and why is it happening?

Comment: Your validation code doesn't exit the method, so the `FindDay` method call happens even if the validation fails.

Comment: This would be an excellent time for you to learn to use the debugger to stop through the code to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Just put the last 2 lines in an `else { string dayString = FindDay(...` block

Comment: @Ken White i'm just about to learn debugging in the next chapter!

Comment: You could either do what @StephenMuecke mentioned or use a try/catch block, so you can catch that exception and display an error popup message.

Comment: @CarlosParra, Throwing and catching exceptions is expensive. Avoid it where possible.

Comment: Also one other stupid sounding question why don't I have to put a new keyword before      int maxDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); I have to create a new object for the first time I declare a new DateTime object why not for the second time?

Comment: Basically, DaysInMonth(year, month) is a static method of the DateTime class, which means you don't need to create an instance of the DateTime class in order to access it. See more here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Comment: If you don't have to give information about what part of the date is invalid. You can `if(DateTime.TryParse(x+y+z, out myDate)){message}`. Either it's  not a valid date or  `myDate.DayOfWeek`. It can be clear 3lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int maxDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth( year, month );  // set a breakpoint here, and see what happens
if ( day > maxDays )
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invaild date");
}
else
{
    string dayString = FindDay(year, month, day);
    MessageBox.Show("You were born on a:" + dayString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to show message to explain why the date is not valid you can simply `TryParseExact` it into a `DateTime`.
No need to convert to int, To check the number of day in the month.

```
var inputs = new List<inputDate>
{
    new inputDate(1,1,2018),
    new inputDate(32,1,2018),
    new inputDate(1,13,2018),
    new inputDate(1,1,-2018)
};

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    GetDayOfBirth(input);
}


private void GetDayOfBirth(inputDate input)
{
    CultureInfo invC = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
            $"{input.D}/{input.M}/{input.Y}",
            $"d/M/yyyy",
            invC,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out DateTime birthday)
        )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You were born on a:" + birthday.DayOfWeek);
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date");
}
```